# Can i use workflow to update lookup field

Tags: visualforce, workflow

**Account** and a **Contact** have look up to a **City** object.  When i change the **city name** the changes must reflect in both objects.
can i create workflow in this case

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question right, you cannot currently do this through workflow.

Your best alternatives are:

1. Create a formula to read the city name from the City__c object on both Account and Contact
2. Update the fields via an Apex trigger on City__c.

Comment: Safe harbor, but since publisher actions added a framework for declarative features setting lookup values they're planning to support this in workflow in the future at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can update a lookup from a workflow rule using a Flow and Flow Trigger.  This is a pilot feature that you need to request to have enabled in your org. Once turned on, a workflow rule calls a flow trigger which in turn calls your Visual Flow which in turn can set/update the lookup field. 
When requesting the feature, ask for "Headless Flows/Flow Triggers" to be enabled in your org.

Answer (score -1):

Lookup is kind of field that stores both Id and Name of parent object.
So if you change city name value of lookups will change authomaticly.